# Run event handler functions synchronously after a React state change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I know `useEffect` allows you to run a function after state is updated.

However, I want to run different logic after a state change based on which different event handler causes a state change.

#### Context

I have a `Parent` component that shows or hides a child `DialogModal` component based on the `[isDialogShown, setIsDialogShown] = useState(false)` in `Parent`.
When `isDialogShown`

The `Parent` passes `setIsDialogShown` and 2 event handler callbacks to `DialogModal`: `onDismiss` (which adds focus to some element) and `onConfirm` (which adds focus to another element).

When `onDismiss` or `onConfirm` on the `DialogModal` is pressed, `setIsDialogShown(false)` should run first to hide the `DialogModal`, then run the respective callbacks to focus on differing elements of the page.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [isDialogShown, setIsDialogShown] = useState(false);
  
  // These need to run after Dialog is closed.
  // In other words, after isDialogShown state is updated to false.
  const focusOnElementA = () => { .... };
  const focusOnElementB = () => { .... }; 

  const handleDismiss = () => {
    setIsDialogShown(false);
    focusOnElementA() // Needs to run after state has changed to close the modal
  }

  const handleConfirm = () => {
    setIsDialogShown(false);
    focusOnElementB() // Needs to run after state has changed to close the modal
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={() => { setIsDialogShown(true) }>Open dialog</Button>
      <DialogModal
        isOpen={isDialogShown}
        onDismiss={handleDismiss}
        onConfirm={handleConfirm}
      />
    </>
  )

}
```

What's the right pattern for dealing with this scenario?

Comment: Just utitlize the useCallback hook, and add a callback to the sate the update call.

Comment: Hi, has an answer here helped resolve your question/issue?

Comment: Yes, thank you! I like your and Jacob's solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight difference to Drew's answer but achieved using the same tools (`useEffect`).

```
// Constants for dialog state
const DIALOG_CLOSED = 0;
const DIALOG_OPEN = 1;
const DIALOG_CONFIRM = 2;
const DIALOG_CANCELLED = 3;

const Parent = () => {
    // useState to keep track of dialog state
    const [dialogState, setDialogState] = useState(DIALOG_CLOSED);

    // Set dialog state to cancelled when dismissing.
    const handleDismiss = () => {
        setDialogState(DIALOG_CANCELLED);
    }

    // set dialog state to confirm when confirming.
    const handleConfirm = () => {
        setDialogState(DIALOG_CONFIRM);
    }

    // useEffect that triggers on dialog state change.
    useEffect(() => {
        // run code when confirm was selected and dialog is closed.
        if (dialogState === DIALOG_CONFIRM) {
            const focusOnElementB = () => { .... }; 

            focusOnElementB()
        }

        // run code when cancel was selected and dialog is closed.
        if (dialogState === DIALOG_CANCELLED) {
            const focusOnElementA = () => { .... };

            focusOnElementA()
        }
    }, [dialogState])

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={() => { setDialogState(DIALOG_OPEN) }}>Open dialog</Button>
      <DialogModal
        isOpen={dialogState === DIALOG_OPEN}
        onDismiss={handleDismiss}
        onConfirm={handleConfirm}
      />
    </>
  )

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use a separate state for the elements A and B to trigger them by in an additional effect. Enqueueing the toggle A/B state ensures the effect handles the update to call the focus A/B handles on the next render after the modal has closed.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [isDialogShown, setIsDialogShown] = useState(false);
  const [toggleA, setToggleA] = useState(false);
  const [toggleB, setToggleB] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (toggleA) {
      focusOnElementA();
      setToggleA(false);
    }
    if (toggleB) {
      focusOnElementB();
      setToggleB(false);
    }
  }, [toggleA, toggleB]);
  
  const focusOnElementA = () => { .... };
  const focusOnElementB = () => { .... }; 

  const handleDismiss = () => {
    setIsDialogShown(false);
    setToggleA(true);
  }

  const handleConfirm = () => {
    setIsDialogShown(false);
    setToggleB();
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={() => { setIsDialogShown(true) }>Open dialog</Button>
      <DialogModal
        isOpen={isDialogShown}
        onDismiss={handleDismiss}
        onConfirm={handleConfirm}
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add another state for which element was triggered and then trigger the effect when the states change:

```
const [action, setAction] = useState('');
// ...code
const handleDismiss = () => {
    setAction('dismiss');
    setIsDialogShown(false);
}
const handleConfirm = () => {
    setAction('confirm');
    setIsDialogShown(false);
}
// Add dependencies to useEffect and it will run only when the states change
useEffect(() => {
   if(!isDialogShown) {
      if(action === 'dismiss') {
          focusOnElementA()
      } else {
          focusOnElementB()
      }
   }
}, [action, isDialogShown])
```